# Can't get Facebook user id by Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an iOS app and noticed that one user is not loaded when I do a requestForMyFriends.

After looking more into this it seems that the Graph API explorer also doesn't return anything for the particular Facebook user. It's a user and not a Fanpage or something.

So:

I've the page for example (which when I enter In my browser will bring up the Page nicely): https://www.facebook.com/user-name

https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/user-name

Will return:

```
{
    id: "https://www.facebook.com/user-name"
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/user-name

Will return:

```
{
    error: {
        message: "Unsupported get request.",
        type: "GraphMethodException",
        code: 100
    }
}
```

http://findmyfacebookid.com/ wil return nothing.

The graph API will return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I'm trying to reproduce this with my test Facebook account and put all restrictions to the max but I always get a nice result with a FacebookId.

My question:
What settings do I need to change to my test Facebook account to reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unsupported GET Request" covers many situations, but at the root the message means you tried to request something via the API which is not available to you via the API

For a request which attempts to retrieve data about a known username or user ID the most likely reasons are:

- User has blocked your app
- User has disabled all platform apps in their privacy settings
- User has deactivated their account
- User has deleted their account

if i had to bet, I'd say it's the second one in this case

Comment: Yeah second one it is. I reproduced it with another account.You can disable the platform apps here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=opt_out&view

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the parameter, you don't have to pass in the whole URL of a profile, just the username/profile-id.

For example: we want to get the info of Mark Zuckerberg. His Facebook username is **zuck**. The URL would be https://graph.facebook.com/zuck and will return the following output

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

Using https://graph.facebook.com/4 (4 is the profile id of Mark Zuckerberg) would produce the same output.

**Edit**
After some further investigation it turned out that said user might have deactivated her account and that is why you see this error. I have used a testuser of one of my apps, went to *Settings -> Security -> Deactivate my account* and taxa, every request to the Graph API returned the result you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks but when I do that I get the same error as the API (added to Q also) :{
error: {
message: "Unsupported get request.",
type: "GraphMethodException",
code: 100
}
}

Comment: Do you use any special library to make the request? Post the code you use to make the request, maybe there is an error :-)

Comment: It's not the code because I can see the problem without using the code.. My question is about why I cant get a Facebook ID for a paticulair Facebook user page without using any iOS code but just using the API.

Comment: I added an example of a Facebook page to the question which is not working

Comment: My last idea: maybe the first comment was right and said person turned off the Facebook Platform (can be done here https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=opt_out&view). Did you already check that?

Comment: I have a new clue and tested it with a test account. When you deactivate your account (Settings -> Security -> Deactivate my account) requesting the info through the graph API will end up in an unsupported get request error (demo: https://graph.facebook.com/100004088294458)